# Is passing variables as arguments & getting desired return value essentially same as passing pointers?

Tags: c, pointers, return

I tried two approaches for passing values to functions, and both seem to have same effect.

**1)** `Passing pointers`

```
int foo(int *bar){
    *bar = doSomething();
}

int main(void){
    int foobar = 0;

    foo(&foobar);
}
```

**2)** `Passing variables`

```
int foo(int bar){
    //do stuff
    return bar;
}

int main(void){
    int foobar = 0;

    foobar = foo(foobar);
}
```

So does it mean that using appropriate `return` i can simulate the same effect as when I use pointers as arguments?Are they basically same and it's just a matter of choice and style/syntax?

I hear pointers complicate code and so as a general rule of thumb one should avoid pointers.

Comment: Please read more about pointers, this is a very powerful tool, and it is not just a matter of syntax.

Comment: I think you mean `foo(&foobar)` in the first example.

Comment: By using pointers, you are not returning since you're passing address of parameter and it gets modified. But using methods, they are off the stack once they exit the function and hence you need to return the value.

Comment: There is a bit of style that go into both, but the second way completely avoids the opportunity for your own code to suffer a `NULL` pointer dereference. With larger objects (e.g., `struct`s), the former way tends to be faster because it doesn't have to copy the memory to push onto the stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular example both has the same effect: they both update the value of `foobar`, but the way in which they are updated are completely different.

In the case 1 you pass the address of `foobar` inside `main` to the function `foo`. This address of `foobar` gets stored into the `bar` argument variable in the function `foo`, and `bar` points to `foobar`. Because now you have the address of `foobar` and the object's lifetime has not finished, you can access the storage of `foobar` directly , and modify it.

```
       +--------+                                    
       |   55   |     +------call foo(&foobar)-----+
       +--------+     |                            |                              
int    | foobar |     |                            V
       +--------+     |    +--points to--------+--------+
       | 0x1234 |-----+    |                   | 0x1234 |
       +--------+<---------+                   +--------+
                                 bar (  int *  |   bar  |        )
                                               +--------+
                                               | 0xabcd |
                                               +--------+
                             At this moment bar holds the address of foobar
                             *bar = whatever will assign whatever to the address
                             which is held by bar, and thus changing the value
                             of foobar in main
```

In case 2, thing is different. You pass the value of `foobar` to `foo` which is held up in the variable `bar`. In `foo` you do not have direct access to the object `foobar`. You can do whatever you want with the value inside `foo`, it won't affect the `foobar`. When you return some value, `foobar = foo(foobar);` statement assigns the returned value into `foobar` this is when `foobar` gets updated.

```
       +--------+                                    
       |   55   |-------------call foo(foobar)-----+
       +--------+                                  |                              
int    | foobar |<-+                               V
       +--------+  |                           +--------+
       | 0x1234 |  |                           |   55   |
       +--------+  |                           +--------+
                   |             bar (  int *  |   bar  |        )
                   |                           +--------+
         foobar = foo(foobar);                 | 0xabcd |
                   |                           +--------+
                   |             {
                   |               //change bar
                   |
                   +-------------- return bar;
                                 }

                              Here bar does not point to anything, it just has
                              copy of the value of foobar. Whatever is returned
                              by foo will be assigned in foobar in main
```

A point to note is that, when you pass the address, actually a value is copied to the `bar`, which is later interpreted as an address. I suggest to read more about pointers, it's a powerful tool.

Answer (score 3):

Half of C is pointer, you haven't got what C is until you master the pointer concept.

It's not always possible to use just return value. In fact, many APIs uses return value only as success/error indicator code, while the real return value is put in the pointer parameter. For instance, a networking library might have the following usage:

```
if (AcceptClient(&ClientInfo) == SUCCESS) { ... }
```

Pointer parameter also serves for multiple return value:

```
if (GetConfigString(&StrData,&StrLen) == OK) { ... }
```

One cannot really avoid pointers when programming in C. However, in languages with pointer abstraction support, that is where pointer to many different objects is managed and the complication is hidden from programmers, it's indeed better to use the abstraction rather than the plain pointer as it reduces a lot of problems that might occur when dealing with pointers. For instance, in Object Pascal you have dynamic arrays, ansistrings, widestrings, etc. All of them are pointer abstraction. One does not need to handle the storage (de)allocation, access of elements, do range checking, etc. everything is handled by the code injected by the compiler. Thus, even when an error happens (e.g. accessing element outside of valid indexes), the error is easily tracable.

Answer (score 2):

They may seem the same but there's not!!Even though both use `pass-by-value` to pass arguments,how they are used is very much different.When you pass pointers as arguments to a function,whatever manipulations you carry out by dereferencing those pointers in that function body are reflected in the original values of the variables that these pointers point to,even though these `passed pointers` may be copies of the "original" pointers declared in `main()`.You see, **more than one** pointers can point to a variable and hence the variables' values can be changed by dereferencing any of these pointers.

But while you pass variables as arguments,instead of pointers, all manipulations on the value of those variables are not reflected in the values of the "original" variables.Those changes are confined to those `copies` that are passed as parameters.

In your example,had you wished to assign the value of `return of foo()` or that of `doSomething()` to a variable other than `bar` and intended not to alter `bar`'s value,then only passing variables as argument is desirable,not pointers.

Here is some simple code that illustrates it:

//`Passing variables as arguments`

```
#include<stdio.h>

int foo(int bar){
    bar=303;

}

int main(void)
{
    int foobar = 0;
    printf("The value of foobar before function call is %d\n",foobar);
    foo(foobar);
    printf("TThe value of foobar after function call is %d",foobar);
}
```

**Output** : `The value of foobar before function call is 0`

```
       `The value of foobar after function call is 303`
```

//`Passing pointers to variables as arguments`

```
#include<stdio.h>
int doSomething();

int foo(int *bar){
    *bar = doSomething();
}

int main(void){
    int foobar = 0;
    printf("The value of foobar before function call is %d\n",foobar);
    foo(&foobar);
    printf("TThe value of foobar after function call is %d",foobar);
}

int doSomething()
{
    return 303;
}
```

**Output** : `The value of foobar before function call is 0`

```
       `The value of foobar after function call is 0`
```

And at last,about **pointers making code complicated**,well,pointers are one of the most elegant features of C and are a very useful and indispensable tool once you know how to use them well.

Answer (score 1):

ya both are same. you could use anything. But, your first code must be

```
int foo(int *bar){
    *bar = doSomething();
}

int main(void){
    int foobar = 0;

    foo(&foobar);
}
```

Because bar is of pointer type and it needs an address of the variable as argument.
Hence foobar will be a variable and &foobar will be pointer.

Generally, these things will be called as call by value, call by address.
Refer wiki for call by value, and call by address.

```
//Call by Address
    void SwapIntAddr(int* ptmp1, int* ptmp2) 
    {
        int ptmp;
        ptmp  = *ptmp1;
        *ptmp1 = *ptmp2;
        *ptmp2 = ptmp;
    }

//Call by Value

    void SwapIntVal(int tmp1, int tmp2) 
    {
         int tmp;
         tmp  = tmp1;
         tmp1 = tmp2;
         tmp2 = tmp;
    }


int main(){
  int a = 3, b= 5;

  SwapIntVal(a,b); // This will have no effect
  printf("%d %d\n",a,b);

  SwapIntAddr(&a,&b); // This will have effect
  printf("%d %d\n",a,b);

}
```

Refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15043170/c-c-troubles-with-pointers-and-functions/15043304#15043304) for more detailed example.

Comment: There is no `call by reference` or `call by address` in C.There is only `call by value`.

Comment: @SheerFish ya `call by referenece` is a C++ Feature. But, `call by address` is there in C: Sample.C `void swap(int* a,int* b){

}
int main(){
    int a = 56,b=59;
    swap(&a,&b);
}
` Executes well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, either style works. There are pros and cons to each.

The `return` style can take constant arguments.

```
int foo(int bar);   foo(42);  // works
void foo(int *bar); foo(42);  // nope
void foo(int *bar); foo(&42); // still nope
```

The pass-by-address style (also known as "out-parameters") relieves string functions (for example) of memory management, and lets them return an error code.

```
int strcpy(char *src, char *dst) { /* nice simple while loop */ }
char *strcpy(char *src)          { /* welcome to malloc hell */ }
```

Also, pass-by-address can save stack space and copying overhead when working with structs.

```
struct quux { /* lots and lots of stuff */ };
struct quux foo(int bar) { ...; return s; /* have to fit a struct quux on stack */ }
int foo(int bar, struct quux *result) { /* write stuff into *result */; }
```

In general, it is preferred to `return` where at all possible, and only use out-parameters where necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Its a little more than "matter of style" discussion here. Code is written so the machine works, but 99.9% of "real-world" code is written for humans to understand.

And humans understand words, sentences, idioms etc.

One of the common idioms in C is:

"If a function must change/alter the contents of an object(variables, structures variables, union variables etc) then pass the handle to the object by value."

Which means, you must `pass-the-object-by-reference` to the function. This is where your approach#1 works well, and seasoned programmers know what you are trying to do with it.

On the other hand another idiom says:

"If the function behaves like a purely mathematical function, where `f(x)` is always equal to `y`, then pass the object itself by value, and use the return value"(not sure if I framed it well)

Which means, for every `x`, if the value of `f(x)` never changes, then use the approach#2.

This conveys the other programmers exactly what you are trying to do. I hope this explanation helps.

Regardless, both approaches do the same work, and outputs are the same.